# Combine two data tables with null values on both tables - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, datatables

I have two data tables as shown below.

datatable1:

```
table1_id(PK)  DriverID    Vehicle    
   111          Ram00       VRN01       
   112          Shyam00     VRN02
   113          Ram00       VRN03
```

datatable2:

```
 table2_id(PK)  DriverID     exit_time 
   AA1          Ram00        10.10AM      
   AA2          Hari00       11.20PM
```

Combined Output

```
table1_id     DriverID    Vehicle     table2_id   exit_time 
   111          Ram00       VRN01       AA1         10.10AM 
   112          Shyam00     VRN02       NULL        NULL
   113          Ram00       VRN03       AA1         10.10AM 
   NULL         Hari00       NULL       AA2         11:20PM
```

DriverID  is common in both table. But just merging two datatable will not give this result.
Please help to achieve this.

```
datatable1.Merge(datatable2);
```

Comment: Do a join. You can probably find the right type [here](http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Two Data tables** to combine into **one Data table** via **Coding** and **Remove** the **Extra Column** later the **For loop ends**,**Check my code it will work.**

```
string Qry = "select tab1.table_id,'' as DriverID,vehicle,tab1.driver_id Tab1DrvrID,exit_time from tab1 " +
              "full join tab2 on tab2.driver_id=tab1.driver_id";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(Qry, con);
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            //string DrvrID;
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string Qry2 = "select tab1.table_id,'' as DriverID,vehicle,tab1.driver_id Tab1DrvrID,tab2.driver_id Tab2DrvrID,exit_time from tab1 " +
                   "full join tab2 on tab2.driver_id=tab1.driver_id ";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(Qry2, con);
                SqlDataAdapter daa = new SqlDataAdapter();
                DataTable dtt = new DataTable();
                daa = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                daa.Fill(dtt);

                if (dtt.Rows.Count > 0)//
                {
                    string s=dtt.Rows[i]["Tab1DrvrID"].ToString();
                    if (s=="")
                    {
                        dt.Rows[i]["DriverID"] = dtt.Rows[i]["Tab2DrvrID"].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dt.Rows[i]["DriverID"] = dtt.Rows[i]["Tab1DrvrID"].ToString();
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                }
                dt.AcceptChanges();
            }
            dt.Columns.Remove("Tab1DrvrID");
```

Answer (score 0):

Merge works properly if columns from two **DATATABLES** are matched in the same **DATATYPE**. If the column has a **NULL** value in the first row of **DATATABLE** the column **DATATYPE** will be String. So the second **DATATABLE**, if have value Date or any other type, will miss the match on merge . To resolve this problem you need to make the two **DATATABLES** columns same **DATATYPE**.

```
    private DataTable MergeDataTable(DataTable dataTable1, DataTable dataTable2)
    {
        var dtCloned = dataTable2.Clone();

        foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable2.Columns)
        {
            var col = dataTable1.Columns[column.ColumnName];
            if (col != null && col.DataType != column.DataType )
            {
                dtCloned.Columns[column.ColumnName].DataType = col.DataType;
            }
        }
        foreach (DataRow d in dataTable2.Rows)
        {
            dtCloned.ImportRow(d);
        }

        dataTable1.Merge(dtCloned);

        return dataTable1;
    }
```